Why is there no "update:" conventional commit? Should we always use "feat:" when updating?
I am learning the conventional commits. I am curious if we update some feature or a little of code patch, why don't we use "update:" in the conventional commits?
I have read that there is feat: and fix: keywords for the conventional commits. Anyone knows why there is no "update:" keywords for the conventional commits or we can add them or am I missing something here?

What would be an example of an update that isn't a feature or fix?

A commit is per definition an update

What do you need update for? For me, "update" is the umbrella term for the given keywords: fix, feat, chore refactor, style, etc. Because adding a feature (feat), revising fonts, images or CSS class (style), rebuilding existing code (refactor) or fixing a bug (fix) are all subordinate to the "update". I'm afraid you have to label your code change that you want to call update with a keyword made up of these "specific" words that are subordinate to the term "update".
And if you don't like that, you can adapt the Git commit conventions for your project and add update (of course in consultation with your team, if there is one)
